# How to Connect a Java-based Machine Learning Framework to a MySQL Database Using PHP?

Tags: java, php, mysql, machine-learning, datumbox

I want to connect the [Datumbox machine learning framework](https://github.com/datumbox/datumbox-framework/) to a MySQL database using PHP.
Datumbox is an open-source Machine Learning Framework written in Java. Unfortunately I could not find any example to complete this task. I would appreciate any help to complete this task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use datumbox api:

- Common API URL: http://www.datumbox.com/machine-learning-api/
- API doc PDF: http://www.datumbox.com/files/API-Documentation-1.0v.pdf

As you can see it used REST `JSON` API, so i think it will be not hard to used it.

**EDIT:**

Also for this API exits PHP client:

http://www.datumbox.com/files/Datumbox_APIclient_PHP_1.0.zip

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to use it like a lib/package with PHP not using their API. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, i thought you want run it use API. I not strong in Java, so probably some other can help you with this issue.